# "console.error" the action "NAVIAGTE" with payload was not handled by any navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

after implementing nesting navigator I am getting error in dishdetail it is not getting render I followed documentation and tried this

```js
onPress = {
    () => navigate({
        name: 'Dishdetail',
        params: {
            screen: "Dishi",
            dishId: item.id
        }
    })
}
```

but still error.

Answer (score 0):

You Navigate function should be like this.

```
onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Dishdetail', { screen: "Dishi" , dishId: item.id })}
```

According to your provided code, you didn't define any route with the name of `Dishdetail`, So change your `Dish detail` to `Dishdetail` like below.

```
<Homenavigator.Screen
            name="Dishdetail"
            component={Home}
        />
```

Comment: Can you make a snack on the expo with this error? I also edit my answer, try now.

Comment: exporting in snack.expo throwing me some error can you please check my git rep                                               
https://github.com/omansh22/res-native
check code in  res-native/components/menucompo.js

Comment: nesting of navigation done in res/native/components/maincompo.js

Comment: Okay, i will look into.

Comment: have you replaced this line `onPress={()=>navigate('Dishdetail', { screen: "Dishi" , dishId: item.id })}` with this 
`onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Dishdetail', { screen: "Dishi" , dishId: item.id })}
` I have seen in your code it's still same as above.

Comment: Also, I have been observed you didn't define any route with the name of `Dishdetail ` in `maincompo.js` so you have to define the route too.

Comment: `const Dis = createStackNavigator();

function Dishd(){
    return(
        <Dis.Navigator
        initialRouteName='Menu'
            screenOptions={sc} 
        >
            <Dis.Screen name="Dishi" component={Dishdetail} />
            <Dis.Screen name="Menu"  component={Menu}/>
            <Dis.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
        </Dis.Navigator>
    )
}`

tried to route maincompo.js with above code now showing some different error of

Comment: same error and Do  you have a screen named "DishD" please correct it .